# Finding the most profitable gig

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Assuming you're a freelance contractor and only take on 1 contract at a time, come up with an algorithm that chooses the most profitable non-overlapping jobs from the list below:

```
potential_contract_jobs = [
  {
    "start_day": 1,
    "end_day": 5,
    "profit": 100
  },
  {
    "start_day": 5,
    "end_day": 6,
    "profit": 10
  },
  {
    "start_day": 15,
    "end_day": 20,
    "profit": 500
  },
  {
    "start_day": 10,
    "end_day": 10,
    "profit": 150
  },
  {
    "start_day": 9,
    "end_day": 12,
    "profit": 20
  },
  {
    "start_day": 11,
    "end_day": 12,
    "profit": 796
  }
]
```

Additional Info:

I saw a this question posted as a potential job interview question and I think it's a great question but it's completely stumped me.

The approach I've tried (and failed) started similar to this:

1. Iterate the list and automatically select any jobs w/o overlaps
2. Sort the list of jobs w/ overlaps by profit
3. Start accepting them in order of profitability

This fails once you address the idea that in a given range of time multiple jobs might be more profitable than taking 1 long one...

I'd love to find a solution, even if it's pseudo code.

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest to start from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling

Comment: @maks: That problem isn't really anything like this one. In job shop scheduling, tasks can be run in parallel, all tasks must be completed, and while jobs have fixed lengths, they don't have to take place at fixed times.

Comment: The link above doesn't answer your question directly. It gives you a clue how can you incorporate the ideas in that article to solve your problem

Comment: @maks can you please remove your initial comment? it's not an answer and only adds confusion. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For only 6 jobs, you have 2^6 possibilities of choices of jobs.
Well feasible to just enumerate.
Then check if it is valid, and take the maximum.

Or you can sort by end_day and create a recursive algorithm where the maximum is determined by the maximum of taking the job with profit and be occupied for a while, or not take the job.